# Как убрать фон у кнопки?

Tags: html, css

Сделал кнопку с изображением , но появилась белая обводка. Как её убрать?

```css
body {
  background-color: #808080;
}
```

```html
<button id=myBtn> <img src="http://ic.pics.livejournal.com/gorod_krasoty/44575741/41389/41389_600.jpg" alt=""></button>
```

Comment: Убрать у кнопки внутренние отступы и рамку `padding: 0; border: 0;`

Comment: стандартный ресетер для кнопок выглядит как-то так `{ margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; outline: none; background-color: transparent; }` дальше уже сами решайте что из этого является причиной ваших проблем.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
body {
  background-color: #808080;
}

button {
  outline: none; /* Для синий ободки */
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<button id=myBtn> <img src="http://ic.pics.livejournal.com/gorod_krasoty/44575741/41389/41389_600.jpg" alt=""></button>
```

Comment: Что за день, почему постоянно минусы?))

Comment: кому-то перешли дорогу))

Answer (score 0):

```
button {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]